# How to refactor these?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, generics, refactoring

I wonder how to refactor a piece of code like this. It is a method in controller and I'm passing 2 SelectLists to Html via ViewBag.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var teacherInfo =  context.Teachers.OrderBy(x => x.Id);
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList = from s in teacherInfo
                                             select new SelectListItem
                                             {
                                                 Value = s.Id.ToString(),
                                                 Text = s.FirstName + " " + s.LastName.ToString()
                                             };
    ViewBag.TeacherId = new SelectList(selectList, "Value", "Text");

    var studentInfo = context.Students.OrderBy(x => x.Id);
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectListStudents = from s in studentInfo
                                             select new SelectListItem
                                             {
                                                 Value = s.Id.ToString(),
                                                 Text = s.FirstName + " " + s.LastName.ToString()
                                             };
    ViewBag.StudentId = new SelectList(selectListStudents, "Value", "Text");


    return View();

}
```

I've tried this but it seems i can't use generic like this because T has no definition for Id and other fields:

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<SelectListItem>> GetSelectListItem<T>(IOrderedQueryable<T> dbData)
{
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList = from s in dbData 
                                             select new SelectListItem
                                             {
                                                 Value = s.Id.ToString(),
                                                 Text = s.FirstName + " " + s.LastName.ToString()
                                             };
    return selectList;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What are the types of `teacherInfo` and `studentInfo`? Can you provide class definitions?

Comment: Your first refactoring task would be to move the query code out of the controller.

Comment: depending on whether your `Teachers` and `Students` inherit from a common class that has required fields, you could do something along these lines: `GetSelectListItem<T>(IOrderedQueryable<T> dbData) where T: CommonPersonBase`

Comment: This question is probably better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to constraint the T to an interface which contains those properties

```
internal interface IListItem
{
    int Id { get; }
    string FirstName { get; }
    string LastName { get; }
}
```

Then make your student and teacher implement this interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic class for Students and Teachers classes to inherit.

```
public class BaseClassForSelectItems
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

 public class Students: BaseClassForSelectItems
{ 
}

  public class Teachers: BaseClassForSelectItems
{ 
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var teacherInfo = context.Teachers.OrderBy(x => x.Id);
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList = await GetSelectListItem(teacherInfo);
        ViewBag.TeacherId = new SelectList(selectList, "Value", "Text");
        var studentInfo = context.Students.OrderBy(x => x.Id);
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectListStudents = await GetSelectListItem(studentInfo);
        ViewBag.StudentId = new SelectList(selectListStudents, "Value", "Text");
        return View();
}


    private async Task<IEnumerable<SelectListItem>> GetSelectListItem<T>(IOrderedQueryable<T> dbData) where T : BaseClassForSelectItems
    {
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList = from s in dbData
                                                 select new SelectListItem
                                                 {
                                                     Value = s.Id.ToString(),
                                                     Text = s.FirstName + " " + s.LastName.ToString()
                                                 };
        return selectList;
    }
```